# Use a proxys for all windows requests

Tags: windows-xp, http-proxy

How do I configure a proxy for all the HTTP requests that is send from my windows PC? Could you please guide me?

I have a Charles Proxy which is available on a system and I need all HTTP requests which is send from my Windows PC to go through this Charles Proxy. I'm using `Windows XP Professional 32 bit`

Answer (score 2):

Open the **control panel**, click on **internet options**, click the **connections** tab, click **LAN Settings**. The proxy settings should be there.

Comment: I don't think all the applications uses this setting...

Comment: @Don .. why not?